# CSV file rows getting cut at the end

Tags: python, csv

Currently I have a original CSV file that I want to manipulate. the [3] value of each row i.e row[3] contains a string that has the letters "HKD " and a number. I am attempting to create a new CSV file that removes the letters and the white space. For some reason when I do so about the last ~60 rows get cut off. I have attempted to print out all the rows and they display just fine in the python shell but will not print onto my CSV. I am unsure of why. The csv output file gets cut off at row 1931, but it doesn't completely cut off the entire row it just displays 1931 in the first column but not rest of the data.

the print out around index 1931:

```
['1929', '8163 ', 'Merdeka Financial Services Group Ltd.', '154']
['1930', '8179 ', 'Food Idea Holdings Ltd.', '153']
['1931', '8079 ', 'Easy Repay Finance & Investment Ltd.', '150']
['1932', '8106 ', 'Zheda Lande Scitech Ltd. - H Shares', '149']
['1933', '1160 ', 'Grand Investment International Ltd.', '149']
['1934', '8363 ', 'SDM Group Holdings Ltd.', '148']
```

and below is my code:

```
import csv
csv_in = open('mcapdata.csv','rb')

writer = csv.writer(open('final-HK-MCap.csv','a'))

for row in csv.reader(csv_in):
    row[3] = row[3].replace('HKD ','')
    writer.writerow(row)
```

I don't understand why it would print in the shell just fine but not output it onto my csv file. Are there bad practices in my python code that causes this situation?

Comment: I can't see anything obvious in the data. You don't `.close()` the files at the end. Does that change anything if you open `'final-HK-MCap.csv'` separately, pass it to `csv.writer()` and then do `.close()` on the file at the end? What might be an aside to your problem, see [here](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/) for using `with` to cleanly open and close files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that the file buffer is not being written out when the script ends.  Calling `.close()` on the file pointer object will flush the buffer.  The pythonic approach is to use the `with` context.

```
import csv

with open('mcapdata.csv','rb') as csv_in, open('final-HK-MCap.csv','a') as csv_out:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_in)
    writer = csv.writer(csv_out)

    for row in reader:
        row[3] = row[3].replace('HKD ','')
        writer.writerow(row)
```